# RESTful Workflow Service Endpoints in WF4 / WCF

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Folks,
  I'm building a pretty standard workflow that I want exposed via a WCF endpoint - I'm using the "WCF Service Application" project template and I've got a .xamlx service. This is a very simple document interchange workflow service - I want consumers to POST me a blob of XML as the body of an HTTP post (with HTTP headers containing authentication tokens). In response, these consumers will get a blob of XML containing the reply. 2 goals for me using REST/POX here are the document/message-based nature of the interaction AND I want to make client development easy for non-.NET environments (especially limited environments like Silverlight and iPhone).

I don't really see how to make this possible using out of the box features (unless I'm missing something). Does anybody know how to create a RESTful (or even REST-ish, I'm not picky) endpoint for a WF4 service-hosted workflow? Any info leading in the right direction here would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no out of the box activities that will allow you to use REST with WF, the Receice is pure SOAP.

You can either build a custom REST Receive activity and use that with your workflow. Depending on your needs this is going to be quite a handful to a lot of work. The easy option is use use a standard REST WCF endpoint and convert the REST data to SOAP, pass rhe request on to the workflow, and do the reverse on the result message.

Comment: So basically just wrap the workflow endpoint in a custom endpoint? e.g. Customer calls RESTserviceA , which grabs data, packages it and then invokes .NET standard WS client proxy and calls ServiceA.xamlx ?

Comment: Kevin - were you able to implement it? I am looking into something similar, any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: The WF CodePlex site has this: http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebAPIWorkflow.  It's not released yet, and seems not to have been updated for a while.  If you're interested, up-vote the UserVoice request for it: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2309159-expose-a-workflow-service-through-rest-json-endpoi.

Answer (score 2):

There is an unreleased [item on CodePlex](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebAPIWorkflow) to cover this, which includes source code.  Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11916218/439024) which contains another idea for achieving this.

If you'd like to see the CodePlex activity released, please up-vote [the UserVoice request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2309159-expose-a-workflow-service-through-rest-json-endpoi).

**Using a REST Pass-Through Service**

As @Maurice mentions, you can also treat the WF service as a back-end service and expose a REST service that simply calls through to the WF service.

This method is a bit clumsy, but has the advantage that it doesn't use anything unreleased or really complicated.

If the back-end service runs on the same machine as the REST service (which is probably what you'd do), you should expose the WF service using the **named pipes binding**.  This binding is *fast*, but only works when the caller and callee are on the same box.

A further thought: your REST pass-through service is blocked while the back-end service is being called.  If your WF service is not very fast, you'd benefit from making your REST service **[asynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx)** so it doesn't block a thread pool thread while the WF service is being called.