# Call WF Workflow from Browser

Tags: wcf, url, workflow-foundation, param

OK, I've searched the Internet for the answer to this and haven't found anything... maybe I'm missing the obvious here or just asking the wrong question, but...

How do you call a WF WCF Workflow just by it's URL with parameters? I have a Workflow xmlx, we'll call it DeepThought.xamlx, an operation named TheQuestion and I need to pass the parameter Answer = 42 to it.

I've tried http://localhost:8042/DeepThought.xamlx/TheQuestion?Answer=42 and just about everything else I can think of. I've scoured the Internet and even the wsdl but am either just flat out missing the answer or simply not seeing it.

I assume it's possible, otherwise, what's the point? Clues appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the workflow as a regular activity (non service) inside WCF. This gave me the ability to use their parameters and pass them to the workflow directly. In the end, not too difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

At least out-of-the-box this is not possible. The standard `Receive` 
activity uses SOAP. I'm sure it's possible to implement a custom Receive but I guess it would be a non-trivial amount of work.

You can also take a look a the following questions. They are REST-related but still may give you some options (a community RESTful endpoint is being mentioned, no idea of its current state though):

- [RESTful Workflow Service Endpoints in WF4 / WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678129/restful-workflow-service-endpoints-in-wf4-wcf)
- [WCF Workflow Service REST interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612278/wcf-workflow-service-rest-interface)